# I have a NSXMLParser in a backgroound thread. Does it calls its delagtes methods in a background too?

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I have a NSXMLParser in a backgroound thread. Does it calls its delagtes methods in a background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but this is easy to check.  Just put a breakpoint on your delegate implementation and then look to see which thread is calling it by looking in the threads/stacks inspector.

If you need the call to go back to the UI thread, look at this

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: